# Can I import an image to use for annotations or a signature in the macOS Preview app?

Tags: macos, preview

I use the Preview app (within macOS) and I'd love to add a traditional stamp to some documents.  I note that under **Tools > Annotate > Signature > Manage Signatures...** I can use either the trackpad or camera to add signatures.

Is there a way to import pictures (or even better, vectors) to my signatures without using the trackpad/camera?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's any other way than just printing the photo out and then add it with the camera.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://michaellynn.github.io/2015/07/26/exploring-os-x-preview-signatures/) goes into details of how the data was stored prior to macOS 10.10. Effectively, it was a plist file in the user's Library that contained values encrypted by a key stored in the keychain. The signature data itself was a serialized NSBezierPath.

On more recent versions, the entire signature file has been moved into a keychain entry called "Signature Annotation Privacy." [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/430454/105377) goes into a little bit of information about it.

However the author of the above blog post mentions that the data format seems to have changed, so it may no longer be stored as an NSBezierPath.